# Distribute task among employees equally

Tags: c#, algorithm

Imagine that I have four employees and twelve tasks like a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l.

First employees 1,2,3,4 should have a,b,c,d and after completing all employees, it should should start from first employee(e,f,g,h) etc

In certain case if task completed at employee2, when the new task arrives assigning should start from employee3 etc

In the code below I am taking the variable for last assigned employee and getting the employees count and task count from the database, assigning to the task to the employee, check uniqueness for tasks and saving to DB.

Code I tried:

```
    int j = 0, LastAssignedEmployee =0;
         var Employees = dbcontext.Employees.Select(m => m.ID).toList();
         var Tasks = dbcontext.Tasks.toList();
         for (int i = 0; i < Tasks.Count(); i++)
         {
             if (i == Employees.Count()-1)
             {
                 j = 0;
             }
             if (i == Tasks.Count()-1)
             {
                 LastAssignedEmployee = Employees[j];
             }
             Tasks Task = dbcontext.Tasks.Find(Tasks.ID);
             Task.EmpID = Employees[j];
             dbcontext.SaveChanges();
         }
```

But I want this to be more standardized and automatic, Is round robin algorithm suitable for this problem or any algorithm for this approach.

Can anybody help me with this cheers.

Comment: Looks like your application uses a database back-end. If so, an SQL query (in a stored procedure) may perform this allocation process much more efficiently. SQL is fantastic for working with _sets_.

Comment: Use modulo to compute the employee index.